# Ruby installation error caused by original partition - dual booting OSX Mavericks

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-mavericks

After messing up the permissions on my original OSX installation I decided to create a new partition with a new installation of Mavericks.

All's fine until I try to install ruby and get the error

```
/bin/sh: /Volumes/Macintosh: No such file or directory
```

"/Volumes/Macintosh" is a trimmed "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" which is where the original OSX installation is on the original partition. I assume it's still required for booting.

Why is the new installation on the new partition looking at the original when trying to install Ruby, and other things, and how do I stop it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks, Steve

Update: Installing ruby using "rvm install 2.1" gives me the error -

```
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install libksba', showing last 15 lines of 
/Users/bigmac/.rvm/log/1394034844_ruby-2.1.1/package_install_libksba.log
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libksba/libksba-1.3.0.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libksba-1.3.0.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libksba/1.3.0
==> make install
Making install in m4
/bin/sh: /Volumes/Macintosh: No such file or directory
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: How are you installing Ruby?

Comment: brew install ruby or rvm install 2.1 [or whatever]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used was to fix my original installation permissions. I did this by restarting the Mac and holding down CMD-R then selecting Reinstall OS X following the instruction here:

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13871

The [re]installation completely restored all permissions without affecting data. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing my issue after installing homebrew and running brew doctor where it told me macports could cause some issues . ( I hadn't installed macports ) It was on the system from a previous version of OSX . By uninstalling [macports](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) I was able to successfully install ruby 2.1.1 .

If that doesn't work there is also an issue if your xcode command line tools are installed in a directory whose name has spaces in it. Apparently  [RVM can't install ruby if there are spaces](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html).

Don't know if it will help but it worked for me

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Miguel. Solved the problem as written above. Steve